# jQuery plugin divided into individual methods

Tags: jquery, methods, plugins

I found aproach how to develop jQuery plugin divided to individual methods in old website of jQuery (see: https://web.archive.org/web/20110325183117/http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Is this approach up to date? This section is no longer available on the new site.

I'm trying to find an article or an existing plugin so I can look at the overall solution - unsuccessfully.

Do not you know about something?

All articles about developing JQ plugin are very simple without method (all main code is in this.each loop , that's how I do not want to use it)

Comment: The pattern hasn't changed much, but the guide is very out of date. I'm not sure why you'd even look that up on archive.org if you want the modern pattern...? This is the up to date version: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: Where do you see a division into methods? Curent version is very simple (without detailed explanation).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that point of your post. That is still a good way of allowing users to access methods of your plugin.

Comment: Yes, but Im looking for better explanation this conception or some existing lightweight plugin for learning how to do this - unsucessfuly. 

But I'm glad that you understand what I'm looking for.

Comment: The functions are stored in an object in the plugin (named `methods`). When the plugin is called with a string argument the logic checks if the string matches a property name in the object. If it does, it calls the function stored against that property name and applies any arguments which were provided.

Comment: I understand basic concept and and the benefits of this approach. I would like to see some existing lightweight plugin (how to share/transfer $this lement between methods etc ... I see storing with data() method, but i would like to see in practice. 

I dont want see only plain skeleton, understand me? :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you want then, as the link you posted originally has that. Whatever you find is going to look identical

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I searched on SO and finally found two patterns that i  like. 

I have only problem with first pattern, I dont know how edit code which can accept arguments of update method.

Code is here: http://jsbin.com/pibejuk/edit?html,output

Some idea? Can you help me?

Comment: SOLVED! 
```
       if (typeof option == 'string') {
            $plugin[option].apply($plugin, Array.prototype.slice.call( data, 1 ));
        } else {
            $plugin.init();
        }
```